# Reusing view across different activities with out separate inflation( To Implement admob across activities)

Tags: android

Is there any way I can Use AdMob(or a View if I become more general) across different activities without inflating it separately from each activity (I don't want the ad to restart every time when an activity changes)....And I want it to work from Versions 2.1 and Higher(Therefore I cannot use fragments)

Comment: See if the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8284194/add-admob-advertise-to-each-and-every-screen-of-android-app/8284766#8284766) helps.

Comment: Actually you can use fragments if you use the android support library and using a main activity layout with fragments taking up the below the add area see http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by using fragments,backporting the fragments might be possible which I haven't tried yet.

Answer (score 2):

You are actually best off recreating the ad each time. You can do this, but you'd most likely need to make a serializable version of the AdMob (or View) and pass the view to the next activity in your intent. Serializing an AdMob view is no small feat.